# How to understand this number with "double scientific"-notation (~1e-9-4.999e-1) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, numbers, scientific-computing, scientific-notation

I'm running a calculation that outputs a matplotlib plot with a vertical axis scaled with (see image below).

```
~1e-9-4.998e-1
```

This is very weird scaling and I'd like to make sure I understand the notation correctly. Does it mean the following?

```
0.000000001 - 0.4998 = -0.499799999
```

So far I haven't been able to successfully google this. I would really apprechiate if someone could help me clarify this.

[image: Plot showing y axis in question]

Comment: Afaik one is a scaling factor and one is just a constant offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lagerbaer is right. The first number (`1e-9`) is the scale of the axes, and the second is a shift. So the tick marked `-8.25` really means `(-8.25)*1e-9 - 4.9984827e-1`, or `-0.00000000825 - 0.49984827 = -0.49984827825`